# How do you define specific channels in Marketing Control Panel/Sitecore Analytics?

Tags: experience-analytics, personalization

In Sitecore 9 `Experience Analytics`, how do you define specific channels in `Marketing Control Panel -> Taxonomies ->Channel->Online` such as paid search ,referral  to `Experience Analytics- Acquisition dashboard`?

### Approach I followed :

1) Created Traffic Type for Bing Ads:

[image]

2) Existing Taxonomies-Bing Ads

[image]

3) Mapping traffic type to taxonomies in `Sitecore.Analytics.Compatiblity.config`

```
    <add trafficType="95" channel="{B55EC2C2-CD7A-4E03-B155-EEFDAE872B7D}"/>
    </trafficType>
```

But the traffic is not recorded checked the interaction table.Please let me know what am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore defines marketing taxonomies as

> A taxonomy is a hierarchical structure that you can use to identify and organize information. In the Sitecore Experience Platform, you can use taxonomies to classify marketing activities, such as campaigns, goals, and events.

I find it easier to understand when i think of it more like "tagging" the Sitecore activities.

The are four types of marketing taxonomies available out of the box:

- Channels
- Campaign groups
- Assets
- Venues

Channels are only used in Campaigns. So in order to have channel data on your experience analytics, you will need to have pages that are tagged to a campaign with a channel. You can start by

1. [Creating a campaign](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/the-campaign-creator.html) and set the channel field to your desired channel.  (Remember to Deploy the campaign through the workflow)
2. [Associate the campaign](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/associate-a-campaign-with-an-item.html) to a page.
3. Visits to this page will be associated to the campaign/channel in your experience analytics dashboard.

You can read more about Marketing Taxonomies [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/marketing-taxonomies.html)

You can also create your own [custom channel](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-a-channel.html) if you want

**Update 1 : Traffic Type vs Channels**

You might have gotten confused with Traffic Type vs Channels. They are essentially the same thing, just different terms/system used in Sitecore versions.

- Traffic Type is the term and system used in versions earlier than Sitecore 8.0
- Channel is the new term and system used in Sitecore 8.0 and later

The process of mapping Traffic Types to Channel is only applicable if you are upgrading CMS from earlier versions (e.g 7.5 to 9.0), so that the information is not lost after the upgrade.

[Sitecore's documentation quote](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/map-traffic-types-to-channels.html)

> In the Sitecore Experience Platform (xDB) version 8.0 and later, the Marketing Taxonomy includes channels that replace traffic types. Channels enable you to classify the different paths that contacts use to interact with your website.
>
> If you have upgraded from an earlier version of Sitecore or have created your own custom traffic types, then you need to map your existing traffic types to channels

Comment: updated approach of mapping traffic type to the paid search , but its not working.Is bing Campaigns has to be created rather than mapping the paid search -bing ads taxonomies?

Comment: @sindu, i think you are going the wrong direction with mapping of traffic types (please see my updated answer). The original answer is still the same, you will need to have campaigns with channel in order to have "channel data" in your analytics

Comment: Thanks @fredric .Can u share Analytics configuration related documentation material for sitecore 9.

Comment: @sindu Sitecore analytics is pretty much baked in when you run Sitecore 9. The only thing u need to get running is adding the visitor identification tag. I don't really have a good answer for you, you can probably start reading from https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/enabling-tracking.html